# A mailing service that includes newsletter and newsletter templating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-email, newsletter, html-editor

I need to allow users to fill in their own newsletter content and deliver it to their own lists. A complete newsletter engine have to have the following key features:

- HTML editor and uploading images.
- Ensure delivery.
- Emailing list and handle unsubscribe issues.
- Reports on emails status (Opened, Marked as spam, Bounce ...etc).

Now I need to make my Rails app contain fulfill these key features. I have looked at some emailing services like SendGrid, Postmark, PostageApp and others. They can support all points except the first one. I need to integrate an Email templating and editor engine that will ease creating new content for newsletters. Is there a service that could provide me with such feature? Or is there a mailing service that could facilitate creating such a feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is [Campaign Monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/). Here is their [API](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/api/), here is their [editor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/create/)

Answer (score 0):

[MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/features/) allows you to create custom HTML templates, if that is what your are looking for. They also have a WYSWYG editor for non-HTML savvy users.

Comment: Can I integrate that with my web application? and can I get the newsletter reports through API calls?

Comment: You can definitely grab stats from the API. There is not an "embeddable" version of the drag-and-drop editor to my knowledge, but you can upload templates in their HTML template language via the API.

Answer (score 0):

[Sendloop](http://sendloop.com/?f=YBB-BD) gives detailed reports, beautiful templates and detailed HTML editor. It has also very competitive pricing.